# How to Align text horizontally inside VB.Net Combo Box

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I cannot find a property that would allow me to align text inside vb.net combo box. Text Boxes have TextAlign Property, but Combo Box does not have that. Is there another property that is used by Combo Box? Or is there another way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the combo's `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDownList` you can do it by owner drawing the items. To do that set its `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDrawFixed` and put something like this in the `DrawItem` event:

```
If e.Index >= 0 Then
    Using st As New StringFormat With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far}
        e.Graphics.DrawString(sender.Items(e.Index).ToString, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, st)
    End Using
End If
```

Comment: @LarsTech: It does if the `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDownList` but not otherwise. I'll update my answer to explain that.